# How to recover from accidentally removing the sudo group

Tags: 18.04, sudo, groups

I am using Ubuntu 18.04. I accidentally removed the sudo group. Is there any way to recover from this? I still have access to the `root` account. I tried to add the sudo group again with the root user, but this did not work, and I got an `errorcode 10`.

Comment: If you have the 'root'  account enabled (with its own password), you can login with root & correct.  If you don't, probably the easiest way to fix is using a 'live' environment (eg. install media), and make the change that way...

Comment: I have acess to the `root` account. But I have no idea how to recreate the `sudo` group. Mayby you cann explain that a littlebit more

Comment: What exactly did you try, and what was the complete text of the error? If you attempted to recreate the group from the recovery shell, did you remember to remount the filesystem in read-write mode first?

Comment: I tried `addgroup sudo` the erros are: `/etc/ group / could not be locked; try again later` and `addgroup: /user/sbin/groupadd  -g 1002 sudo: returned errorcode 10`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This [link](https://www.maketecheasier.com/fixing-sudo-error-in-ubuntu/) helped me, then adding the `sudo` group with `sudo addgroup sudo` and adding my user to group with `sudo adduser -aG username sudo` worked.

> 1. Reboot the computer. If Ubuntu is your primary and the only operating system in your computer, press the <kbd>Shift</kbd> button
>      when it is booting up. This should make the GRUB screen show up on
>      your monitor. On the GRUB screen, press the down keyboard key to the
>      Recovery mode and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
>
>    [image: ![enter image description here]
>      <sup>**Ubuntu GRUB
>      screen**</sup>
> 2. On the next screen, select *Check all file system (will exit read only mode)*.
>
>    [image: ![enter image description here]
>
>    When you see the message `Finished, press Enter`, press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
> 3. Next, select *Drop to root shell prompt*.
>
>    [image: ![ubuntu-select-shell-prompt]
> 4. You will now be at the command line. Type:
>
>    ```
>    usermod -a -G admin username
>    ```
>
>    Replace the username with your own login user name.
> 5. That’s it. Now type `exit` and select *Resume normal boot*.

Comment: Tested in 20.04. It works, but "admin" has been replaced by "sudo". Tks.