# No entry for user 'passwd'

Tags: server, permissions, sudo, password, root

I got a chicken and egg thing going on. My username isn't in the sudoers file and I can't set a password for my root to edit files when it returns *No entry password for the user 'passwd'.* It's weird that it regards 'passwd' as user.

As of now I can't do a simple command such as `sudo apt update` since the username isn't in sudoers file and I can't enter root to edit the file.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu ! Which release of Ubuntu you have installed ?

Comment: It's the 18.04.

Comment: Does this work for you https://askubuntu.com/questions/1059954/how-to-recover-from-accidentally-removing-the-sudo-group ?

Comment: This works. Thanks!